# Automatically detect change in rss feed

Tags: python-2.7, rss

In my webscraper, I currently monitor a RSS feed and save the first title to a variable. Then I have a 1 Minute timer to go back and check the title against the first variable.

IFTTT has a nice way of doing it, but are there any python modules or libraries to automatically detect change? At the same time, I can't be certain if they are just running a very short timer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some RSS servers support a push protocol.  Check the [RSS Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_Cloud) element with [feedparser](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/uncommon-rss.html#accessing-feed-cloud).  Then use [xmlrpclib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) to establish a persistent connection with the RSS server.

Your server may support [PubSubHubbub](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/PubSubHubbub), which is similar.